# Programatically firing an event in GTK (With Gtk2Hs)

Tags: haskell, events, gtk, gtk2hs

I am using Gtk2Hs (EventM module) to handle GTK events within Haskell. Is it possible to manually (re-)fire an event?

Upon detecting an event on one widget, I want to refire this event on another widget.

I am using Gtk2Hs version 0.10.1 and GHC version 6.10.4.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think you'd need to call the glib/gasyncqueue function g_async_queue_push, but that's not exposed in the haskell bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any idea if it would be a simple matter to write the bindings for this? My experience with the FFI is slim to none.